# Highlight Duplicate Column ONLY When Specific Text is Present

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, highlight, worksheet-function

I only want to highlight duplicate rows ONLY if the cell in a column contains a specific value.

For example, in Column 3 if the cell contains "Apple" and Columns 1 and Columns 2 match, highlight the rows.

[image]

The formula for conditional formatting I'm using looks like

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1000,$A1,$B$1:$B$1000,$B1,$C$1:$C$1000,"Apple")>1
```

This formula highlights the whole row if ANY of the criteria is met, so it'll look like, notice Column1 on the last row:

[image]

I've googled so many times, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: when I do it, it highlights the second to that last not the last, still wrong but not the reason you state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this formula, you need to include the value in column c also:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,"Apple",$C:$C,$C1)>1
```

[image]

Comment: After making a few tweaks, it worked! Thanks so much! So one thing I found is if I put criteria for an even amount columns and including the value in "column c", the column where the text is located, the row wouldn't highlight and total an odd amount of ranges. Can you explain this by chance?

Comment: Also, is there a way to lock down conditional formatting into a table? everytime i enter data, the conditional format freaks out and changes ranges.